# When a widget opened an app, can the app knows the widget size

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

When tap on an iOS 14 widget it opened the app:

```
var body: some View {
    Text(entry.text)
        .widgetURL(WidgetEntryView.deeplinkURL)
}
```

Can the app get the size (small, medium, large) of the widget that open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Environment(\.widgetFamily)` and pass it in `widgetURL` or `Link`:

```
struct Widget1EntryView: View {
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var widgetFamily

    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var deeplinkURL: URL {
        URL(string: "widget-deeplink://widgetFamily/\(widgetFamily)")!
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Link("Tap me", destination: deeplinkURL)
            Text("Widget family: \(String(describing: widgetFamily))")
                .widgetURL(deeplinkURL)
        }
    }
}
```

Then detect opening this URL in your main App:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .onOpenURL { url in
                print(url) // prints `widget-deeplink://widgetFamily/systemSmall`
                print(url.lastPathComponent) // prints `systemSmall`
            }
    }
}
```

---

<sub>Here is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pawello2222/WidgetExamples#deeplink-widget) with different Widget examples including the DeepLink and Environment Widgets.</sub>